# Custom Taxonomy Links For Custom Post Types Not Working

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have set up a custom post type and a custom taxonomy.  Then I am displaying the list of taxonomies as a set of links so that if someone clicks on that link, it should bring up all the posts under that taxonomy.  Currently this is not working.  It keeps taking me to the 404 page with the 'This is somewhat embarrassing isn't it?' message.

Code is as follows:

**FUNCTIONS.PHP**

```
add_action( 'init', 'build_taxonomies', 0 );

function build_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy( 'companies', 'companies', array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Company Categories', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true ) );
}

add_action('init', 'register_mypost_type');
function register_mypost_type() {
  register_post_type('companies',array(
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => 'Companies',
      'singular_name' => 'Company',
      'add_new' => 'Add New Company',
      'add_new_item' => 'Add New Company',
      'edit_item' => 'Edit Company',
      'new_item' => 'Add New Company',
      'view_item' => 'View Company',
      'search_items' => 'Search Companies',
      'not_found' => 'No companies found',
      'not_found_in_trash' => 'No companies found in trash'
    ),   
    'public' => true,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt'),
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'companies'),
    'taxonomies' => array('category'),
    'menu_position' => 7,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false
  ));
 }
```

Then on another page called 'page-company.php' I use the following code to output the list of taxonomies as links:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'companies' );
wp_list_categories( $args );
?>
```

When I hover over one of these links the URL is displayed as:

```
'http://localhost:81/?companies=graphic-design'
```

Graphic Design being one of the categories I have added to my custom taxonomy.

However clicking this link always takes me to the 404 page.

I have set up an archives page called archive-companies.php and I thought all of this would do the trick.

Any help that anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you get a 404 if you switch to _pretty_ permalinks?

Comment: @DavidChase thanks for your reply.  Yes I still get the 404 page if I make the switch.

Comment: Probably worth noting that if I add the newly created categories from my newly added taxonomy to the default 'Category' taxonomy that exists by default for posts in Wordpress, then it works a treat.  Obviously I want to have separate ones but I thought maybe this working is part of my problem?

Comment: do you have wp debug on?

Answer (score 2):

OMG OMG OMG ... after days reading posts on how to solve the issue, using rewrite rules and ussing permalinks rewriting code, your solution was the only one that worked perfectly!
The only change I needed to apply was in the custom taxonomy declaration:

This code

```
         'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'pubs/type',
                'with_front' => false
             ),
```

for this code

```
            'rewrite' => true,
```

and that was it. Working like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

#### Note:

Prior to my re-writing I tested your code and also got a 404.

**1)** I re-wrote you your custom post type and **used your custom companies** category.

**2)** Then I cycled from default to `/%postname%/` and it works.

`Functions.php`

#### Here you go the custom post type:

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function register_mypost_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Companies', 'Post Type General Name' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Company', 'Post Type Singular Name' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Company' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Company'),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Companies'),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Company'),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Company'),
        'add_new'             => __( 'New Company'),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Company'),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Company' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search companies' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'No companies found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'No companies found in Trash'),
    );

    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                => 'company',
        'with_front'          => true,
        'pages'               => true,
        'feeds'               => true,
    );

    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'company'),
        'description'         => __( 'Companies Posts' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', ),
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'companies' ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 100,
        'menu_icon'           => '',
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'query_var'           => 'company',
        'rewrite'             => $rewrite,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
    );

    register_post_type( 'company', $args );
}


add_action( 'init', 'register_mypost_type', 0 );
```

#### Your custom category

```
add_action( 'init', 'build_taxonomies', 0 );

function build_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy( 'companies', 'companies', array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Company Categories', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true ) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Been away for a few days.  This unfortunately doesn't work for me.  Can you confirm the URL you see when you hover on a category please?  I get http://localhost:81/companies/graphic-design

Comment: yes it works for me, with the URL and everything, make sure you are using the code you see above because with your code i was getting a 404 as well, also remember to cycle through the permalinks and make sure Wordpress has writing permissions to `.htaccess`

Comment: In the 'Your custom category' code bit, the second param for the register_taxonomy function should be the CPT name 'company' registered in the code snippet above it, not 'companies' which is not the custom post type registered. Will work if changed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create `taxonomy-companies.php` template in the root directory of your theme. This template will be responsible for displaying your taxonomy term posts.

then on that template you need to use the `get_queried_object()` to get all the taxonomy details.

e.g;

```
$queries_obj = get_queried_object();
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $queries_obj );
echo '</pre>';
```

it will return

```
WP_Term Object
(
    [term_id] => 10
    [name] => Featured companies
    [slug] => featured-companies
    [term_group] => 0
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 10
    [taxonomy] => companies-category
    [description] => 
    [parent] => 0
    [count] => 2
    [filter] => raw
)
```

then query posts like below.

```
$q = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' =>  'companies', // post type name
    'posts_per_page' =>  get_option( 'posts_per_page' ),
    'tax_query' =>  array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => $queries_obj->taxonomy,
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' =>  array( $queries_obj->term_id )
        )
    )
) );
if ( $q->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) :
        $q->the_post();

        // loop do stuf
        the_title();

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_query();

endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your WP-Admin go to Settings and Permalinks. Don't change anything, just click Save Changes and the custom taxonomy page will work.